# Proper way to deploy docker services via Gitlab CI/CD to an own server

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

My application is built using 3 Docker services:

- backend (React)
- frontend (Node.js)
- nginx (routing traffic)

Up until now I was **manually** logging into an own Digital Ocean server, cloning the repository and launching the services with `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`.

I want to **automate** the process from now on.

Given Gitlab CI/CD Pipelines and the runners, **what would be the best approach to automatically deploy the code to Digital Ocean server**?

[WHAT I WAS THINKING OF, might seem very "beginner"]

Idea 1: Once a commit was pushed to master -> Gitlab runner will build the services and then copy it over to the DO server via `scp`. Problem: how do you launch the services? Do you connect to the DO server via `ssh` from the runner and then run the start script there?

Idea 2: Register a worker on the DO server just so when it pulls the data from Gitlab it has the code on the DO server itself. It just has to build them and run. But this approach is not scalable and seems hacky.

**I am looking for some thinking guidelines or a step-by-step approach.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the benefits of using Docker in a production-deployment scenario is that you don't separately `scp` your application code; everything you need is built into the image.

If you're using an automation system like Ansible that can [directly run containers on remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html) then this is straightforward.  Your CI system builds Docker images, tags them with some unique version stamp, and pushes them to a repository (Docker Hub, something provided by your cloud provider, one you run yourself).  It then triggers the automation system to tell it to start containers with the image you built.  (In the case of Ansible, it runs over ssh, so this is more or less equivalent to the other ssh-based options; tools like Chef or Salt Stack require a dedicated agent on the target system.)

If you don't have an automation system like that but you do have ssh and Docker Compose installed on the target system, then you can copy *only* the `docker-compose.yml` file to the target host, and then launch it.

```
TAG=...
docker push myname/myimage:$TAG
scp docker-compose.yml root@remote:
ssh root@remote env TAG=$TAG docker-compose up -d
```

A further option is to use a dedicated cluster manager like Kubernetes, and talk to its API; then the cluster will pull the updated containers itself, and you don't have to ssh anything.  At the scale you're discussing this is probably much heavier weight than you need.

Comment: Indeed Kubernetes will be overkill at this stage.

This solution seems bright to me, thanks!